# Facebook Graph API: Getting latitude/longitude of a Checkin via Fields API (optimized calling)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location, field, facebook-checkins

I'd like to know whether there is a way to directly get the latitude/longitude fields via the Facebook Graph API.

The background is that I want to reduce the amount of data which is returned by the Graph API by getting rid of fields which are not of interest for my application.

I know there's something like this working in the Graph API Explorer:

```
me/?fields=id,checkins.fields(id,place.fields(id,location),created_time)
```

It returns the following:

```
{
"id": "12345", 
"checkins": {
"data": [
  {
    "id": "101511234546244", 
    "place": {
      "id": "170048419682121", 
      "location": {
        "street": "", 
        "city": "Frankfurt", 
        "state": "", 
        "country": "Germany", 
        "zip": "", 
        "latitude": 50.108641831527, 
        "longitude": 8.6654729704433
      }
    }, 
    "created_time": "2012-11-08T08:30:48+0000"
  }
]
}
```

As I don't need the address parts of the location, I'd really like to get rid of them as well. If I try this the follwoing way, it doesn't work:

```
me?fields=id,checkins.fields(id,place.fields(id,location.fields(latitude,longitude)),created_time)
```

The result is

```
{
"id": "12345", 
"checkins": {
"data": [
  {
    "id": "101511234546244", 
    "place": null, 
    "created_time": "2012-11-08T08:30:48+0000"
  }
]
}
```

Did somebody have success in doing something similar? If so, I'd be great if you could let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API documentation and the Graph API explorer, `Subfields are not supported by location` so you are unable to extract just `latitude` and `longitude` from the location object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you maybe post the URL to the documentation? The Graph API explorer doesn't show me the message you mentioned unfortunately.

Comment: Have a look at: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fcheckins%3Ffields%3Dplace%2Clocation.fields(latitude%2Clongitude)

Comment: Yeah, but I think your query is wrong: location is a sub-object of the place object. From my perspective the http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fcheckins%3Ffields%3Dplace.fields(location.fields(latitude%2Clongitude)) query should be conceptually correct, but it return null as place.

Comment: Either way, the error message is clear. Facebook doesn't let you pull out subfields from the location object.